# PDFs missing EOF section on customer's server

Tags: asp.net, pdf, itext, eof

Folks- I'm relatively new to ASP.NET, and have a question that has stumped my peers-- folks much more experienced than myself.

My company created a website that uses iTextSharp to build and stream PDFs. The functionality works perfectly on my company's development and staging/test servers. The customer's functionality isn't working well, however. The customer's server streams a file where the PDF is missing the last block of data representing the EOF section. The PDF seems to build correctly, streams correctly, but when users open the PDF, the following error displays: 'There was an error opening this document. The file is damaged and could not be repaired.'

By comparing the PDFs in a text viewer (comparing the PDFs from my server vice the customer's server), I can see that the EOF section is missing from the customer's PDF. I'll also note that no errors are thrown during PDF creation, if that's helpful. To make matters more difficult, I have no access to the customer's servers, so I won't be able to interact with the systems directly.

The asp.net version is 3.5. Both of our servers (my company and the customer) are: running IIS7.5 on Server 2008R2;  using iTextSharp is 5.1.2;  and are configured for FIPS compatibility.

I've read dozens and dozens of posts detailing why a PDF isn't created properly, why it may not be streaming, and all things related, but I haven't seen this particular issue before. I guess what I need to know in the short-term is: 1) what can I provide to help diagnose the issue, 2) where is a good place to start looking for areas of concern?

Also, I updated to revision 5.5.3 last night; same results-- it works fine on my servers, but produces broken PDFs on the customer's server.

Code added:

```
Public Function BuildReport(ByVal tblReport As DataTable, _
                        ByRef memStream As MemoryStream, _
                        ByRef strErrMsg As String) As Boolean

    Dim booOK As Boolean = True
    strErrMsg = String.Empty

    ' Create document
    Try
        ' Create writer (listens to the document and directs PDF stream)

        memStream = New MemoryStream()
        Dim msWriter As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(_document, memStream)
        msWriter.CloseStream = False

        'Create header
        Dim ev As New itsEvents
        msWriter.PageEvent = ev

        ' Set document metadata

        _document.AddTitle(_strMetaTitle)
        _document.AddSubject(_strMetaSubject)
        _document.AddCreator(_strMetaApplication)
        _document.AddAuthor(_strMetaAuthor)

        ' Open document, add document content, close document

        _document.Open()
        AddReportContent(tblReport)
        _document.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception

        booOK = False
        strErrMsg = ex.Message
    End Try
Return booOK
End Function

Private Sub AddReportContent(ByVal tblReport As DataTable)

    ' Count report columns

    Dim intReportColumns As Integer = 0
    For Each col As DataColumn In tblReport.Columns
        If ContainedInColumnMask(col.ColumnName) Then
            intReportColumns += 1
        End If
    Next

    ' Build table

    Dim table As PdfPTable
    Dim cell As PdfPCell
    Dim phrase As Phrase

    If intReportColumns >= 1 Then

        ' Init table

        table = New PdfPTable(intReportColumns)

        ' Add title to table

        'phrase = New Phrase(_strMetaTitle, _fontLarge)
        'cell = New PdfPCell(phrase)
        'cell.Colspan = intReportColumns
        'cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1 ' 0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right
        'table.AddCell(cell)

        ' Add column headers to table

        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim intColWidth As Integer
        Dim intColWidths As Integer() = New Integer(intReportColumns - 1) {}
        Dim intColWidthTotal As Integer = 0
        Dim strColName As String
        For Each col As DataColumn In tblReport.Columns
            If ContainedInColumnMask(col.ColumnName) Then
                strColName = col.ColumnName
                If (col.ExtendedProperties.Item("NOTEXTEXPORT") <> True) Then
                    If col.ExtendedProperties.Contains("FRIENDLYNAME") Then
                        strColName = col.ExtendedProperties.Item("FRIENDLYNAME")
                    End If
                End If
                phrase = New Phrase(strColName, _fontMedium)
                cell = New PdfPCell(phrase)
                cell.BorderWidth = 1
                cell.BackgroundColor = iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY
                'cell.BackgroundColor = iTextSharp.text.Color.LIGHT_GRAY
                table.AddCell(cell)
                intColWidth = GetColumnWidth(col, strColName, _fontMedium.Size, _fontSmall.Size)
                intColWidths(i) = intColWidth
                intColWidthTotal += intColWidth
                i += 1
            End If
        Next
        table.TotalWidth = intColWidthTotal
        table.SetWidths(intColWidths)

        ' Add rows to table

        For Each row As DataRow In tblReport.Rows
            For Each col As DataColumn In tblReport.Columns
                If ContainedInColumnMask(col.ColumnName) Then
                    phrase = New Phrase(SetBlankIfNothing(row.Item(col.ColumnName).ToString()), _fontSmall)
                    cell = New PdfPCell(phrase)
                    cell.BorderWidth = 0.5
                    table.AddCell(cell)
                End If
            Next
        Next

    Else

        ' Init table
        table = New PdfPTable(1)
        ' Nothing to add to table
        table.AddCell(String.Empty)

    End If

    ' Add table to document
    _document.Add(table)

End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal strMetaTitle As String, _
               ByVal strMetaSubject As String, _
               ByVal strMetaApplication As String, _
               ByVal strMetaAuthor As String, _
               Optional ByVal strColumnMask As String = "")

    GetStaticInfo()

    _strMetaTitle = strMetaTitle
    _strMetaSubject = strMetaSubject
    _strMetaApplication = strMetaApplication
    _strMetaAuthor = strMetaAuthor

    _document = New iTextSharp.text.Document(_itsPage, _itsMarginLeft, _itsMarginRight, _itsMarginTop, _itsMarginBottom)

    If strColumnMask <> "" And Not strColumnMask Is Nothing Then
        _strColumnMask = strColumnMask
    End If

End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal strMetaTitle As String, _
               ByVal strMetaSubject As String, _
               ByVal strMetaApplication As String, _
               ByVal strMetaAuthor As String, _
               Optional ByVal strColumnMask As String = "")

    GetStaticInfo()

    _strMetaTitle = strMetaTitle
    _strMetaSubject = strMetaSubject
    _strMetaApplication = strMetaApplication
    _strMetaAuthor = strMetaAuthor

    _document = New iTextSharp.text.Document(_itsPage, _itsMarginLeft, _itsMarginRight, _itsMarginTop, _itsMarginBottom)

    If strColumnMask <> "" And Not strColumnMask Is Nothing Then
        _strColumnMask = strColumnMask
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please provide enough of your source code to allow people analyze the interplay of closing of iText

Comment: With zero code my two main thoughts are that you are reading and writing from and to the same stream at the same time or you are calling `GetBuffer` instead of `ToArray` on a `MemoryStream` somewhere. My third thought would be that you have code that is compartmentalized to reduce cyclomatic complexity and is passing abstractions like `PdfWriter` and `Document` around. This last option is 100% valid but almost always breaks because implementors (not iText) do it incorrectly. Lastly, you are using a three year old version, try upgrading to see if that fixes it, too.

Comment: That is great advice, given the limited information that is shared. Thanks mkl and Chris.

Comment: I've added code. Also, I moved to version 5.5.3 last night with the same results; it works fine on my servers but does not work on the customer's servers.